# How to check the value of variable in cypress?

Tags: input, cypress

i have a variable ids which gets assigned some value dynamically.

it contains value like so

```
const ids =  ["6fd92108-b1ca-4ce5-ace5-5d16c37ff245"]
```

now in cypress i want to check the value from html dom which is like so

```
<input name="ids" value=["6fd92108-b1ca-4ce5-ace5-5d16c37ff245"] />
```

i check like this

```
cy.expectValue('ids', Array.isArray(ids));
```

this doesnt work as Array.isArray(String(ids)); as it returns false.

how can i assert this properly. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: It is hard to help without knowing what `.expectValue()` is doing.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to try is `cy.get('input').should('have.value', ...)`, since the test needs to check the internal `value` property of the `<input>`.

But the problem is, `value` is always stored as a string type inside the input element, and `const ids =  ["6fd92108-b1ca-4ce5-ace5-5d16c37ff245"]` is an array, so the above will fail to match on **type**.

One way around it is to use `JSON.stringify()`

```js
const ids =  ["6fd92108-b1ca-4ce5-ace5-5d16c37ff245"]
cy.get('input').should('have.value', JSON.stringify(ids))  // passes
```

You can also go the other way, and convert the string to an array

```js
const ids =  ["6fd92108-b1ca-4ce5-ace5-5d16c37ff245"]
cy.get('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .then(valueString => JSON.parse(valueString))
  .should('deep.eq', ids)                                // passes
```